# Configuring ctags for a Node.js project: No tags file

Tags: ctags

I'm attempting to configure ctags for a Node.js project that I'm using, and having some difficulty getting off the ground. My goal is to have my `tags` file live in the `.git` directory. I've browsed through a number of different questions, but none have resolved this specific issue.

I'm running on MacOS Catalina (version 10.15.3), and using iTerm2 as my terminal (version 3.3.7). 
I began by installing ctags using `brew install ctags`. For the sake of eliminating potential issues with multiple instances of ctags, I generated my tags file with the full path to the ctags executable installed by brew:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ctags/5.8_1/bin/ctags -R -f .git/tags --exclude=node_modules
```

I verified that this created the tags file, and that it's populated with data.

From there, I opened a file in vim, and used `<ctrl + ]>` to attempt to jump to a tag. I get this error: `E433: No tags file`

I've gone through a number of iterations of trying to set the tags variable, and none have worked to this point. In my current state, here's the output of `:set tags?`:

```
 tags=~/path/to/my/project/.git/tags,.git/tags;~,./tags;~,./tags,tags
```

I'm not sure what further troubleshooting steps I can take from here, so any additional advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance for the help!

**Update**

I've created a simple reproduction case that exhibits the same behavior. I created a new Node project at `~/Documents/Sandbox/node/ctags_test`. I initialized it with `npm init` and `git init`, and installed Express with `npm install express`. I created this simple `index.js` file:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello, world!');
});

app.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('Ctags server running');
});
```

After this point, I ran the same steps I ran above to generate my tags file in the `.git` directory. After verifying that the tags file was generated, I opened `index.js`, and moved the cursor over the word "express" in line 3, and hit `<ctrl + ]>`. I got the same error as in the previous case.

Comment: Can you share the output of `:echo tagfiles()`?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble it just returns an empty array: []

Comment: That means it’s not finding your tags. Check :pwd, among other things.

Comment: Running :pwd confirms that I'm in a subdirectory of the project that I'm working with. I'm going to spend some time getting a minimal example put together in another project, either to reproduce this or verify that my larger project has another issue

Comment: Added a simple example that exhibits the same behavior

Comment: Might need to check the options `tagcase`, `tagrelative`, `tagfunc`... run `:options` and jump to section 3 (tags)

Comment: Does it work if your `tags` file lives at the root of the project, rather than inside the `.git/` subdirectory? You could add `tags` to a global git ignore list in your machine, so that git would never really try to track `tags` files unless you tell it to explicitly... Would you consider such a solution? (Regardless, your question is a good one, I'll try to reproduce this myself to investigate.)

Comment: @filbranden interestingly, moving it to the root of my project does seem to solve the problem. I'll keep working on debugging the issue with having it in .git, but your workaround should be reasonable for now. Thanks :D